# How to iterate data frame records having with out column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I Have data frame records like below format in HDFS Location and they don't have column names

The below output I have written by using StringBuilder with tab separated.

```
[yahoo.com      899 3   24  0.003   0.026
 apple.com      117 5   101 4.245   0.086
 testdomain.com 6   6   6   1.0     1.0
]
```

The above details describe as columns like `MAIL_ID, TESENT, TEBOUN, TEVET, B_RATIO, C_RATIO`

I have to iterate through each row and call external API by using below JSON Format

```
val subJson = new JSONObject();
subJson.put("TS", System.currentTimeMillis());
subJson.put("TESENT","899")
subJson.put("TEBOUN","3")
subJson.put("TEVET","24")
subJson.put("B_RATIO","0.003")
subJson.put("C_RATIO","0.026")
```

By using subJson I have to invoke external API.

Apreciate your quick help.

Comment: I looked for voted and accepted your answers, I dont know how to do that, Please ping me how to do that.

Comment: you will have to provide details on how you are reading data from hdfs please do so if you require help

Comment: val devVerRdd = sc.textFile(/hdfsOutputPath/12.txt)

Comment: I will convert rdd to json, just give me the first part answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said *you have tab delimited file in hdfs* and you want to

> > iterate through each row and call external API by using below JSON Format

Following architecture should work for you

```
val devVerRdd = sc.textFile(file path in hdfs)

devVerRdd.map(x => {
  val splitted = x.split("\t")

  val subJson = new JSONObject();
  subJson.put("TS", System.currentTimeMillis());
  subJson.put("TESENT",splitted(1))
  subJson.put("TEBOUN",splitted(2))
  subJson.put("TEVET",splitted(3))
  subJson.put("B_RATIO",splitted(4))
  subJson.put("C_RATIO",splitted(5))
   //nvoke external API here
})
```

and *don't forget to trigger action at the end of transformations*